# What happens when a Chrome user uses an NPAPI plugin?

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, npapi

I just recently read here on Stack Overflow that Chrome has dropped NPAPI, does this mean any Chrome user, who tries to use my plugin:

1. Their computer explodes?
2. They receive a warning that my plugin is no longer supported?

If their computer does metaphorically explode, what plugin language most closely resembles c++, and what Linux Lite IDE would you recommend I use to develop cross-platform compatible plugins?

I realize this question is somewhat misleading, because I do plan on answering the main question on my own.Though, I still want to hear your thoughts on what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing happens. Plugins simply don't load, they act the same as they would if plugins were supported and it just wasn't installed.

Depending on what you are trying to do, your best bet is to look at one of these possibilities:

- Implement it in Javascript
- Implement it using emscripten (C++) compiled as WebAssembly
- Implement it as a NativeMessageHost with a Chrome extension
- Implement using some combination of WASM / NativeMessageHost

If you need to do something that you can't do in the browser's sandbox (e.g. access to hardware that the browser doesn't have) then you'll need the NativeMessageHost method. If it's just a question of needing to use a C++ library emscripten is a good way to go.